How to navigate to fragment C from a fragment B in viewpager which is present in fragment A using Navigation Component?
I tried adding the actions in each viewpager fragments, but on click of the button in Viewpager Fragment. The app crashes and displays the following error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.application.module,
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.application.module:id/action_BScreen_to_CScreen cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.application.module:id/AScreen) label=fragment_AScreen class=com.application.module.Fragments.ActivityFragments.AScreen
at
